# The sequence space cs has the Fatou property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

The sequence space cs is defined as the space of all complex or real sequences $x=\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, such that  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_k$ converges.

I was wondering if this space has the Fatou property: A Köthe sequence space $X$ is said to have the Fatou property if for any real or complex sequence $x$ and any $(x_n) \in X$ such that $x_n \uparrow x$ coordinatewise (i.e, $\left | x_n(i) \right | \uparrow \left | x_i \right |$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|< \infty$, we have that $x \in X$ and $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$.

One may try to do the following but it is not clear wheather the last term converges:

$$\|x\|_{cs}= \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\left |\sum_{i=0}^{j} x(i)  \right |\leq \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=0}^{j} \left | x(i) \right |= \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=0}^{j} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left | x_n(i) \right |= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=0}^{j}  \left | x_n(i) \right |$$

I would appreciate your help to see if indeed the cs space has the Fatou property. I have the same doubt with the Hahn sequence space $h$:
$$h=\left \{ x= \left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in c_0 : \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)\left | x_{k+1}-x_k \right | < \infty \right \}.$$
I would also like to know if there are any references that further explain this property and these kind of topics.

Comment: Do you really want $|x_n(i)|\uparrow |x_i|$ and not $x_n(i)\uparrow x_i$?

Comment: @user469053 What would the latter mean if the sequence terms were complex?

Comment: @TheoBendit I guess $x_n(i)\to x_i$ and $|x_n(i)|\leqslant |x_i|$ would be the right condition. But as written, the answer is obviously no.

Comment: It seems that cs is not even a solid space (also: what norm do you use on cs?)

Comment: @PhoemueX  $\left \|x \right \|_{cs} :=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k \right |$

Comment: Again: a sequence space $Y$ is solid whenever from $|x_n|\leq|y_n|$ for all n and $y \in Y$ it follows that $x \in Y$ with $\|x\|_Y\leq \|y\|_Y$. This is implied by the fatou property. The space cs is not solid, so it does not satisfy the fatou property.